# Javascript blur works slower than focus function

Tags: javascript, html, blur, onfocus

I came across with an interesting firing time difference between `focus` and `blur` event listeners.
I added both listeners to window and just wanted to check if both work properly.
Then I realized that `blur` function delays approximately 0.2 seconds.
When I tried to change an element color or some different DOM manupulation both works at the same time but when called `console.log` it has a significant difference.
I have this issue with Chrome and Opera, I don't know why but Firefox doesn't have this issue.

Check the code below.

```js
window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  console.log("focused.");
});

window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  console.log("blured.");
});
```

Comment: The delay doesn't seem to apply to elements on the page (such as an `<input>`). But the fact that Firefox responds to the blur event on the window faster than other browsers likely means it's up to the browser to determine when the blur event occurs. And so the delay could be intentional as part of some validation. The HTML spec doesn't really provide any details or requirements regarding this though.

Comment: Can you explain how did you measure that delay?